# How to Rig This

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I have this Bone Rig that I don't know how to rig.  Think of it like a dog ear.  Here's a picture.

[image: Rig]

I'm trying to figure out how to rig it so that the bones on the right side are the control bones.  The lower right one is the one that moves the lower part of the ear, while the upper right one influences the middle.  Here's some other pictures to show what I'm looking for:

[image: LowerControl]

[image: MiddleControl]

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: you could give an IK constraint to Ear4 and Ear6 with a Chain Length of 2 and the 2 horizontal bones as Targets. Perhaps add some Pole Target as well. I'm not sure that it would be the best way to rigg dog ears that said... (Spline IK?)

Comment: where should I put the poles and targets?

Comment: Not sure pole target is needed, should try without first

Comment: yes perhaps the pole target isn't necessary, but actually do you want to rig a dog ear or do you want to use this particular armature, because another armature good be better for this purpose

Comment: @RBlong2us, stick the pole head to the bone's tail

Comment: the pole facing the same way as Ear_6.001?

Comment: I'm using this rig for a dog ear.  I am up to suggestions on how to change it, though.

Comment: I might subdivide it

Comment: maybe you could use one of my answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb/116128#116128  you could also use physics, more realistic and fun but a little more tricky

Comment: K, thanks.  I'll take a look at it.. looks promising.  I'll let you know if it works.  Thanks

Comment: for physics, tutorial by Alimayo Arango:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c11l2o5uCQs   or Daniel Kreuter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02YYfXC7H8U

Comment: Isn't physics harsh on render times?

Comment: not with these methods as only several vertices are affected by physics, they are used to guide the rest of the mesh, it's worth a try  ;)

Comment: K, thanks.  I'm gonna try manual first.

Comment: Question:  I would like to use B-Bone display for the ears, but the rig doesn't need it except for the ears.  How should I solve that problem?  Should I make the ear rig a separate armature, or would that cause problems?

Comment: edit: yes you could do that, simply parent the ear armature to the head bone of the body armature