# Rigging a pencil case

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So I have this pencil case:

[image: blender pencil case]

And I would like to open it like this:

[image: opened real life pencil case]

Note : I'm not trying to open the zipper, just to deform the pencil case in a realistic way.
I figured the best way to do this would be by rigging it, but the thing is, I don't know much about rigging. I tried this :

[image: useless test rig]

But, as you might have noticed, I kind of have no idea what I'm doing and it really does not work.

So, would you have an idea of how to get a realistic opened pencil case, with or without rigging ?
That would really help me !

Comment: Look for videos on how to use weight painting to control the influence of bones on the object.

Comment: Hook modifiers are an option as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to rig with the *Stretch To* constraint, I give [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm) an explanation for an arm (method #2), it's exactly the same for your pen case, except you'll need several bones all around the object. Also you may want more than 2 segments if the deformation is more complicated:

[image]

You may also want to try *Spline IK* but it's a bit tedious, so if *Stretch To* works fine, then use it.