# Soft Body - how to make a stretch deformation by collision?

Tags: soft-body

I would like this elastic band in Soft Body mode to be deformed in this way by another object.
My simulation is fake and extremly basic it's just to show the event.

[image]

Comment: is your elastic supposed to stay rigid and horizontal on each side?

Comment: @moonboots ow thank you. Not necessarily, I plan to apply this procedure to a lip that is deformed by teeth when we stretch it behind

Comment: so you don't expect the object to create 90° angles like that? rather a curve?

Comment: If my rubber band did that in real life, I would freak out or think it was magnetized or something.

Comment: @moonboots exactly. My goal is that soft body mesh stretch like an elastic when collising with that cube. This would mean, logically, that the mesh must have a thickness so that a stretch can be done without ending up with faces which cross between them?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard yeah lol like a cartoon when a metal bar keep the shape of some one's head

Comment: @moonboots another fake sim (nearest expected) [link](https://i.ibb.co/9NLx6bP/untitled44.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should try with *Cloth* instead of *Soft Body*, the cube needs to be set to *Collision*, then tweak the factors to make your cylinder rigid enough, especially the *Stiffness* values (here 100/100/100/300):

[image]

Comment: Nice ! It bothers me that you modeled all this when I could have given you my blend file! You helped so much. So easy. I think I didn't catch very well the Soft Body's context of use.

Comment: it may be possible with soft body as well

Comment: I would abuse to ask you something else... in case that this rubberband has an armature (a chain of bones all long), is the combination healthy with cloth property ?...

Comment: maybe you should describe the whole thing you need to do. Also, if you have different sequences, you may need to use a technic or another depending on what you need

Comment: This will be the subject of another topic otherwise I will confuse this one. 
I do the rigging of a mouth. Therefore I wanted the lips to have an elastic property which undergoes the collision with the teeth.

Comment: maybe you should simulate with bones rather than using physics? seems to me more adequate but you may have good reasons to use physics?

Comment: maybe you should also look into Spline IK or Stretch To constraints? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm/116128

Comment: lips are yet deformed by armatures combination (bones that deforms mesh and others that only role as muscle)  [this](https://ibb.co/j8kMzkg) and see the slice view [link](https://ibb.co/zrcWxgQ) I want the lips to collide with teeth with realism that only physics give.

Comment: maybe ask a new question with a precise description of what you want to achieve, what you presented here was a solution that may not be the most adequate

Comment: I could not describe my request more clearly. In any case you have put me on good tracks, thank you so much