# Is it possible to create a cartoon mouth using Bezier curve?

Tags: modeling, animation

I am trying to create a cartoon character with a simple mouth, but there are no tutorials that answer my question. Can I use a curve to animate a mouth? And if so, how can I?

Comment: could you please elaborate? What do you mean by use a curve to animate a mouth? You have the Spline IK that allows to use a curve to control an armature for example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm/116128

Comment: Or do you want to use a bevelled curve to make the mouth itself?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a straight answer, but I want the mouth be a hole in a mesh, and the shape of the hole can be changed using a Bezier curve.

Comment: so Spline IK may be a way to do it, click on the link I've given