# How do i make this minecraft eyebrow with bendy bones?

Tags: armature, bones

I want to make a rectangle eyebrow for my character with specific controls, but I'm new to bendy bones and cant figure it out.

I want it to be a rectangle with 2 bones on each side that move each side of the rectangle while still keeping it straight, like this simple drawing I made.

[image]

in the drawing the two bones have moved but the cube (a line here) is still straight.

I also want to have a third bone in the middle which i can move to bend the line up or down in a nice curve.  I think bendy bones are the best way to do this, but I cant figure out how to get this nice way of controlling it.  Is this even possible?

[image]

Comment: maybe take a look at my answer here, I guess the Spline Ik is a bit painful but it's the solution that will give you the most control: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm/116128

Comment: Im trying to follow it, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to select a bone, and then select the curve to hook the bone to it.  I cant get it to work =(

Comment: Select the bone you want in Edit or Pose mode, switch to Object mode, shift select the curve, select the vertex, press Ctrl H > Hook to Selected Object Bone

Comment: Another completely different solution would be to use shape keys, much simpler that all these solutions

Comment: yeah, that would probably be better for what I want to do, but like my first picture I want it to remain straight unless I am bending it down or up and I'm not sure how to rig the two bones controlling either end when the eyebrow has loop cuts.

Comment: I hope that made sense.

Comment: figured it out, using a stretch to contstraint, will post an answer once I've got it the way I want it.