# How do you rig eyebrows?

Tags: animation, rigging

I have this character with eyebrows that are attached to the head. I just extruded some faces above the eyes because I didn't know how else to do it because I haven't seen any tutorials about eyebrows or how to rig them, but I want my eyebrows to be very expressive and do some wavelike movements. I have an armature set up with a head bone, but I don't know where to go from there. Can I create expressions with shape keys or is it more efficient to create bones for the eyebrows? And if it's better to rig the eyebrows how do you do that?
[image]

Comment: Use rigify to apply face armature.... However, much quicker down and dirty way is to use shape keys.

Comment: It depends on how realistic you want the eyebrows. [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/tQd3rDv5iVw) is part 2 of a cartoon face rig that has custom bones for the eyebrows that are separate objects, at one extreme.  Rigify's face rig can take advantage of topology so that eyebrow movement will match skin around the eyebrows tightening at the other.

Comment: you can create 3 bones for each eyebrow, segment them if they are parented to each other, parent them to the head bone. A bit more complicated, you could use a Spline IK, maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From default cube, go in *edit mode*, <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>

[image]

Loop cut like this:

[image]

<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> -> *object mode* -> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd>

[image]

*Add armature > single bone*

<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> *-> select bone ->* <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> -> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> -> then 3 times <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Check "*in front*" to see it like in my image

[image]

Select cube, shift select armature -> *automatic weights*

[image]

If you now go in *pose mode* (select armature first), you can move your bones in z- direction and you get:

[image]

which looks pretty bad.

But if you add a *subdivision modifier* to your cube

[image]

It looks like this and you still can edit the cube as you want to make it even look better.

If you want to make it easier to move your eyebrow bones, you can limit them e.g. by locking all all axis except y:

[image]

[image]

and I would recommend adding a parent bone and parent all these bones to that parent bone so you can freely rotate and place your eyebrow where you want.