# Rigging mesh bends rigidly with Inverse Kinematics

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm a beginner, trying to rig tentacles on my creature.

I have added an inverse kinematic constraint to the end of the tentacle and for some reason when I move it looks very rigid instead of smooth. I have tried to subdivide the tentacle thinking the problem is in the mesh and have also checked the weight paint for each bone.

[image]

Comment: If you've subdivided enough then the problem comes from a bad weight painting, maybe try to parent again. Also you probably could do it with less bones and just segment each bone to get the bend. You can share your file if you want us to take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Tooke me some time to upload but here it is: https://pasteall.org/blend/8aff21a5bc17467fa9ff3f132ac509c4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the mesh, as soon as I created a tentacle with enough geometry everything began bending as expected.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove the *Decimate* modifier, it looks like it messes up your topology and therefore the interaction between the armature and the mesh. More generally, the rest of your topology is a bit too dense and not verty good, you should retopologize, then give a *Subdivision Surface* in order to smooth the whole shape.

Maybe you should work with less bones and segment them. But if you want to keep your current armature, you first need to create additional edge loops at the base of the tentacles, otherwise you won't be able to bend the mesh:

[image]

Once done, if you don't want to reparent the whole mesh, select all the tentacle bones in *Edit* or *Pose* mode, switch to *Object* mode, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, then in the header menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*, this operation will recalculate the weight for the selected bones only (there may be a way to select several bones once in *Weight Paint* mode but I don't know the shortcut):

[image]

**Edit:** From your second file, first you need to disable the *Deform* option of the controller bones, otherwise they will act on the mesh:

[image]

To segment the bones, go into the *Bone* panel and increase the *Segments* value (like 3). You can select all your bones, type the value, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> so that it applies to all the selected bones:

[image]

Now you can recalculate the weights again. You may need to give some small corrections in *Weight Paint* mode. Then it works:

[image]

Also for tentacles, the *Spline IK* constraint is interesting, see my explanations [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm).

Comment: I have done as you suggested: reduced the number of segments and added additional loop cuts as well as recalculated bone weights but it looks exactly the same.

Comment: please share your file again, with the changes you've made

Comment: My apologies in advance if I am not understanding something very obvious. I also really appreciate your help. Here is the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/ec7d4b2fda33421a9d56cb33e7b80294

Comment: No problem, I've edited my answer, please try and tell if it works

Comment: Can you please have a look again? Because I have done everything as you said but it looks the same (facepalm) :  https://pasteall.org/blend/99b88faa5eb140fc8fe9be161618fe78

Comment: It looks like it's caused by this Decimate modifier, what is it for? Disable it and test again. Also you could put a Subdivision Surface modifier under the Armature modifier. The problem is that you mesh is rather high-poly, that's probably the reason why you had to use a lot of bones. Don't you want to retopologize your mesh?