# Animation destroys character arm when moving using bendy bones

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I created a character with a simple cylinder arm and included a bendy bone with 16 segments for animating.

My issue is when I try to move the arm upwards, it looks terrible in the animation because it squishes all my meshes together and looks like a blob

The 2nd image is when it is moving upwards and it just gets deformed

Note I added a lot of loop cuts in the arm so it can bend, yet it looks terrible for animation unless theres a way to soften this or what should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't see how it is possible to make my characters arm move upwards without it looking awful because of the bends in the mesh

Comment: Don't know whether [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCAA1CkWDi0) is any help?

Comment: so what are image 3 and 4, it looks correct here, no? Maybe take a look at this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm

Comment: if both comments doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: @moonboots yes, but the 2nd pic is what happens for me to get to image 3 and 4. So when I set the keyframe you can see image 2 in the animation where it gets crushed