# Animate parented object to move in a certain way when parent object moves itself?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

[image]

This is the machine in question whose movements (1.35 -1.38, source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfpfpzknBo8&t=1m28s) I'd like to replicate via applying armature.

My mesh:

[image]

How do I rig the other 3 limbs so that they move exactly as that machine does in that Youtube link I earlier poster? Thanks

Comment: maybe check the solutions I cite here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm

Comment: @moonboots informative answer, and I'll refer to it in the future. Now, for my question, when I parent objects to another, I cannot get the parented to move in a certain way when the parent moves.

Comment: could you please tell a bit more, maybe show an animated gif or a picture?

Comment: Here is the animated video source:

"This is the machine in question whose movements (1.35 -1.38, source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfpfpzknBo8&t=1m28s) I'd like to replicate via applying armature."

Answer (score 0):

You should create one unique armature and use the *Stretch To* constraint for each arm, as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm). Here is a quick try:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answer was helpful

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. I'll look into it