# Why won't the teeth move and why won't the tail move properly?

Tags: rigging

1. The teeth either doesn't move with the mesh or the bottom teeth stick to the top jaw. I've done so much research but nothing is helping. Please help.

[image]

2. The tail use to move all together smoothly but now it won't anymore. It moves bit by bit and I don't know how to fix it so it moves smoothly again. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=VGVjr4K4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VGVjr4K4/)

Comment: @TheRoyalRadio You can enter the full text given with the image upload into an edit of your question. (I edited that for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Select the head, switch to *Edit* mode, hide the head itself, select the teeth, go into the *Object Data > Vertex Groups* panel, remove the vertices from all groups:

[image]

Now in the list select the Head vertex group and click on *Assign*:

[image]

For the tail, it's not clear what you want to do, in any case you need to loopcut your tail otherwise it won't be able to bend:

[image]

You could use an *IK* constraint on the bone called *Tail bone.026* and make the *Tail Tip* the controller, in that case unparent *Tail Tip*. Or activate the *Auto IK* option and move *Tail Tip* to move the tail:

[image]

But for a tail the best is probably to use the *Spline IK* constraint as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116124/how-to-rig-a-cartoon-style-hose-limb-cartoon-arm).

Comment: I'm trying to select the teeth but when I hide the head, it hides the teeth as well. What do I do to get the teeth separate?

Comment: You need to go in Edit mode, select the head with L, hide with H, the rest should still be visible as you didn't select them

Comment: You've been so helpful. THank you. I just need more help will the teeth because now the bottom teeth stick to the top jaw when it's not supposed to. Also, it messed up the paint job when I move his head. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: the problem is that your rig is not clear, if you want to make the teeth stick to the lower jaw, and if you want to be able to control the lower jaw, you need a proper bone for the lower jaw, and it doesn't exist for the moment, so create it, parent the head again so that the lower jaw vertices are controlled by the lower jaw bone, then re-do the operation for the teeth, remove from all groups, then assign them to the lower jaw this time, not to the head vertex group

Comment: I've tried to do that twice and it didn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: create a lower jaw bone and try to parent, if it doesn't work please share the file again